# Android webview crashes randomly due to SSE call

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, android-webview, server-sent-events

I have a Jquery Mobile 1.4 with Jquery 2.0 webpage which I serve in an Android Webview (Android 4+). All worked fine until I started to use SSE. The App periodically crashes due to a Signal 11 on the WebViewCoreThread.

This happens **only** when navigating from and to pages, and then randomly.

There is no stacktrace, just the Signal 11 at 0x00000000.

This is the javascript code:

```
if ( typeof (EventSource) !== "undefined") {
    // sse
    //console.log("sse");
    chatnotificationsource = new EventSource("php/process_get_chat_notification.php");
    chatnotificationsource.onmessage = function(event) {

        var message = event.data;
        console.log("got message " + message);
        $("#chatnotification").show();

    };
}
```

When I switch off the SSE code there is no problem, so it has clearly to do with the SSE call. I am using the following WebView initialisation.

```
    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
protected void createWebView(int webViewId) {

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(webViewId);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);

    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize(20 * 1024 * 1024); // 20MB
    webView.getSettings().setAppCachePath(
            getApplicationContext().getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath());
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    // load online by default
    webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);

    webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);

    if (!connectionDetector.isConnectingToInternet()) {
        // loading offline
        webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(
                WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
    }

    // clients
    webView.setWebViewClient(customWebViewClient);
    webView.setWebChromeClient(customWebChromeClient);

}
```

I expect is has something to do with Android navigating to another page while the SSE call is running or "processing".

Thanks for your help,
Coenos

Comment: Nobody? I removed the SSE calls from the pages that Webview serves and no more crash appeared, ever.

Comment: Have you fixed this problem? I have same problem. Randomly crash if running Jquery code. Looking forward to more information. Thanks.

Comment: No I havent, I moved away from SSE and webview.

Answer (score 0):

Moving away from SSE in combination with Android WebView fixes the issue. There is no WebView patch/update or workaround for this (yet).